# When writing the date, why do we write "8th December 2013", instead of "8th of December, 2013"?

Tags: dates

I've always been taught to write it alike the former, but personally, I think the latter looks better. Why is it that most people write it alike the former?

Comment: Commas are never required by law, and in a date they are optional. If it's meant to be read out loud, commas make sense because they indicate intonation dips. But if it's intended to be read only -- and always when intended for machine reading -- commas have no purpose. The specified order and separators of the various date parts is much more important for machines.

Comment: I've never used the 'th' or the 'of'. It's always been 8 December, 2013 or December 8, 2013 - Or even more commonly, 12/8/13.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my professional career, it was always *8 December 2013*. Just like that. How you choose to pronounce it is another matter.

Comment: Do you know why that has become the custom, to write it like that?

Comment: It's clear and uncluttered. Commas and 'th' (or 'rd') add nothing.

Comment: Well sure, but then again, nobody ever refers to “the 4 of July” or “the 1 of January” or “the 25 of December” or “Remember remember the 5 of November”.

Comment: 'A date **which** will live in infamy'

Answer (score 0):

I guess, date format depends on the documents and country.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date#Expressing_dates_in_spoken_English